# CruiseControl modificationSet fails to execute when svn points to a url

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol, svnant

In my current CruiseControl setup  I am running the following target:

```
<modificationset quietperiod="30">
       <svn RepositoryLocation="http://my/url/repo/trunk" />
</modificationset>
```

I do a simple checkin of a blank text file and subsequently the messages I receive in the CruiseControl log are as follows:

```
[cc]May-13 15:53:56 Project       - Project mine:  bootstrapping
[cc]May-13 15:53:56 jectController- mine Controller: build progress event: bootstrapping
[cc]May-13 15:53:56 Project       - Project mine:  checking for modifications
[cc]May-13 15:53:56 jectController- mine Controller: build progress event: checking for modifications
[cc]May-13 15:53:59 Project       - Project mine:  No modifications found, build not necessary.
[cc]May-13 15:53:59 Project       - Project mine:  idle
[cc]May-13 15:53:59 jectController- connectfour Controller: build progress event: idle
[cc]May-13 15:53:59 Project       - Project mine:  next build in 1 minutes
[cc]May-13 15:53:59 Project       - Project mine:  waiting for next time to build
[cc]May-13 15:53:59 jectController- mine Controller: build progress event: waiting for next time to build
```

Tortoise: TortoiseSVN 1.6.8, Build 19260 - 32 Bit , 2010/04/16 20:20:11
CruiseControl: 2.8.3

Comment: what's the version of svn and cruisecontrol that you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need a locally checked out version of the repository so CruiseControl has something to compare to, so it can detect changes?

The way we do this in our CruiseControl setup:

We have an initial checkout routine that checks out all the required projects for the build. We use a script/batch file to do this, which operates directly against svn from the command line.

Then we use the following in our CruiseControl setup file:

```
<modificationset quietperiod="60">        
  <svn username="${svn.user}" 
       password="${svn.password}" 
       localWorkingCopy="${dir.checkout}/db4oj" />
</modificationset>
```

For every project that we check out we have one svn entry like the above in the modificationset.

The dir.checkout property will point to a concrete path in the file system.

Comment: yes however that seems completely backwards.  Why would I want a local copy when I have the option to use the url?  That is the entire point of using the url.  However, in the interim I have been utilizing that setup. +1

Comment: Don't you need a local copy on the CruiseControl machine anyway? You use it there to build locally, no?

Comment: That may be the case Carl, but my question is about why the tag does not work.

Comment: If you don't have a local copy, I wonder how Cruisecontrol would detect how a change has happened? Don't you think Cruisecontrol has to compare against something?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer, but this is what you can try:

1. Turn on debug output from CruiseControl, it will print out actual commands issued by CruiseControl engine.
2. Then you will be able to re-run the commands manually and check what's their output.

EDIT:

Adding simple log4j configuration:

```
log4j.logger.net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.sourcecontrols=DEBUG
```

results in not so many message added to the CruiseControl log. Yet enough to learn what `svn` command is executed. In my logs I saw:

```
2010-05-17 20:57:16,808 [BuildQueueThread] INFO  BuildQueue    - now adding to the thread queue: test1
2010-05-17 20:57:16,821 [Thread-22] INFO  Project       - Project test1:  bootstrapping
2010-05-17 20:57:16,821 [Thread-22] INFO  jectController- test1 Controller: build progress event: bootstrapping
2010-05-17 20:57:16,821 [Thread-22] INFO  Project       - Project test1:  checking for modifications
2010-05-17 20:57:16,821 [Thread-22] INFO  jectController- test1 Controller: build progress event: checking for modifications
2010-05-17 20:57:16,828 [Thread-22] DEBUG SVN           - Executing command: svn log --non-interactive --xml -v -r {2010-05-16T22:00:00Z}:{2010-05-17T18:57:16Z} http://localhost/svn/SomeProject/
```

Now, if I issued the same command manually, I get 'empty' XML:

```
$  svn log --non-interactive --xml -v -r {2010-05-16T22:00:00Z}:{2010-05-17T18:57:16Z} http://localhost/svn/SomeProject/
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log>
</log>
```

... as opposed to broader time range, e.g.:

```
$  svn log --non-interactive --xml -v -r {2001-01-01T01:00:00Z}:{2010-05-17T18:57:16Z} http://localhost/svn/SomeProject/
[...]
```

Comment: Turning debug on in cruise control made my eyes bleed.  Is it always supposed to drop a crap-ton of messages out to the console?  None of which were errors.

Comment: In step 1 you weren't looking for any errors. Just the actual `svn` command executed. If it's really too much to be searchable you can try to set `DEBUG` logging for `net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.util` package only. This one contains classes which do the actual command execution.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you another datapoint, I tried this with my (rather old) CruiseControl setup, and it worked.

- CruiseControl v2.5
- Subversion server v1.5.5 (r34862)
- Apache 2.0

I was using a svn:// url so I changed to a http url to match your test, restarted cruise control. Waited for a while (I got distracted for an hour) then commited a change in one of my files in svn. Shortly after, a new build started, triggered by the modification in svn.

EDIT: To clarify, my cruise control was monitoring svn at something like `svn://buildserver/svnrepo/project`. Your OP mentions using a http URL. To get closer to your test scenario, I wanted also to use a http url. I had svn mapped through apache, so I just changed the URL that I was using to where apache was presenting the svn repo, e.g. `http://devserver/svn/svnrepo/project` to get closer to your test scenario.

My point is to show that what you are trying to do does work.

Here's a sanitised snippet from my CruiseControl `config.xml` file. I'm using maven (1.1beta3 !) to build. Crikey, this stuff is old, but it's working.

```
<project buildafterfailed="false" name="someproject-int">
        <plugin name="svn" classname="net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.sourcecontrols.SVN">
        </plugin>
        <plugin name="svnbootstrapper" classname="net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.bootstrappers.SVNBootstrapper">
        </plugin>    
    <labelincrementer separator="_" defaultLabel="rev_1"/>
    <bootstrappers>
      <currentbuildstatusbootstrapper file="p:/build/cc-logs/someproject-int/status.txt">
      </currentbuildstatusbootstrapper>
    </bootstrappers>
    <modificationset>
      <svn repositoryLocation="http://dev/svn/project/trunk" 
      localWorkingCopy="p:/build/checkout/int/project"
      username="build" password="****">
      </svn>      
    </modificationset>
    <schedule interval="300">
      <maven goal="scm:svn-update-project|compile" 
        projectfile="p:/build/checkout/int/project/project.xml" 
        mavenscript="d:/Programs/build/Maven-1.1b3/bin/maven.bat">
      </maven>
    </schedule>
    <log dir="p:/build/cc-logs/project" encoding="ISO-8859-1">
    </log>
    <publishers>
    [...]
    </publishers>
  </project>
```

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? I am a bit confused on how svnUrl != httpUrl

Comment: I should add, a small snippet would be infintely helpful

Comment: Updated my post - hopefully this is clear. The file you checked in, I presume it was under /trunk? What was the output from running svn log --non-interactive --xml -v -r {2010-05-01T01:00:00Z}:{2010-05-17T18:57:16Z} http://my/url/repo/trunk. Change the dates to coincide with the time you checked in the blank text file.

Comment: When you browse your repository, e.g. "http://my/url/repo/trunk" in your OP, do you see a directory listing with you text file? You mentioned tortoiseSVN - what's the version of your svn server?